# Mysql concurrent updates on a row leading to deadlock

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Using mysql 5.7 with storage engine as innodb. I have a table that stores product information. The table looks like this with unique key on productId

```
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| productId | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| seller    | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| updatedAt | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| status    | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| data      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I have two operations via a java app connected to this mysql :  
1. New incoming events (that contain information about product changes) for the productId need to be inserted if they have a version greater than the existing event. The version is stored as a json blob in my data column 
2. Update row for the productId to change the status.

My isolation level is read-committed.
I tried two approaches but both are leading to a deadlock :

Approach1:

```
Transaction1 starts
 Insert ignore into products where productId='X' values();  // Takes a S lock on the row 
 select * from products where productId='X' for update ;    // Take a X lock on the row to prevent new writes and compare the incoming event with the current event
 Insert into products values on duplicate key update values // insert into row and on duplicate key update values
commit
```

A concurrent update will open another transaction :

```
Transaction2 starts
 select * from products where productId='X' for update ;    // Take a X lock on the row to prevent new writes and compare the incoming event with the current event
 Insert into products values on duplicate key update values // insert into row and on duplicate key update values
commit;
```

This is leading to a deadlock in the situation when the following  : 
 
1. Transaction 1 - Insert ignore statement has taken an S lock on the row.  
2. Transaction 2 - Select for update statement is waiting to take an X lock on the row.  
3. Transaction 1 - Select for update statement tries to take a X lock on the row.

This leads to a deadlock because an S lock is being held by transaction 1 and transaction 2 is waiting to take to X lock and when transaction 1 tries to take a X lock, it leads to a deadlock.

Approach 2 :

```
Transaction 1 starts: 
 select * from products where productId='X' for update ; // If a row exists then it will be locked else I know it does not exist
 Insert ignore into products where productId='X' values(); 
commit

Transaction 2 starts:
 select * from products where productId='X' for update ; // If a row exists then it will be locked else I know it does not exist
commit
```

This is leading to a deadlock in the situation when the following  :
1. Transaction 1 - Select for update statement takes an X lock on the row.  
2. Transaction 2 - Select for update statement is waiting to take a X lock on the row.  
3. Transaction 1 - Insert ignore statement tries to take an S lock on the row, but transaction 1's X lock is already waiting for a lock which leads to deadlock

So, I wish to know how to handle concurrent update and insert new events (rather row updates) into my table without leading to deadlocks. 
1. What should be the locking order ?   
2. How to make sure that concurrent updates and new row insertions work without deadlocks. 
  
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it after some experiments, the core problem was with the sequence of S and then X locks taken in one transaction and the X lock taken in another. Basically, the S lock taken at the start was leading to all cases having a deadlock. 
So, I moved the insert ignore statement outside the transaction as the first statement. The transaction now only takes X locks, which means that one of the transaction waits on the other taking an X lock.

Event1 : Inserting a new event

```
result = Insert ignore into products where productId='X' values(); 
if result == null
 return
end
Transaction start
 select * from products where productId='X' for update ;    // Take a X lock on the row to prevent new writes and compare the incoming event with the current event
 Insert into products values on duplicate key update values // insert into row and on duplicate key update values
commit
```

Event 2 : Updating an existing event

```
 Transaction start
   select * from products where productId='X' for update ; // If a row exists then it will be locked else I know it does not exist
  commit
```

So, both the events have transaction that only compete for an X lock, which helped me avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Alternatively, re-apply the transaction that was killed.  You _do_ need to be prepared to do this because something could cause a deadlock or other error fatal to the transaction.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames for your suggestion. Yes, restarting the transaction was an option. But, this was a recurring pattern and the above solution solved the problem. In general, what's your take on deadlocks, shouldn't they be avoided ?

Comment: Some deadlocks can be avoided.  And I agree with _trying_ to avoid them.  However, I find many people on this forum who seem to think all deadlocks can be avoided and spend too much time trying to do so.  I'm glad you solved your own problem.